# APIView Deleteコマンドで、getメソッドが呼び出されてしまう。

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

### 問題点

urls.pyで、ソースコードのように、urlpatternsを定義しました。
BookViewerは、APIViewを継承してget,post,deleteメソッドを記述しました。
postmanなどで、APIコマンドで、GET,POST,DELETEを発行しましたが、DELETEコマンドに対して、getメソッドが呼び出されてしまいます。
何か記述に問題があるのでしょうか？

### 環境

OS:Ubuntu　22.04.1

### ソースコード

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class BookViewer(APIView):
  self get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return JsonResponse({'status':'get'})

  self post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return JsonResponse({'status':'post'})

  self delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .view import BookViewer
urlpatterns = [
    path('book/<pk>/<option>/',BookViewer.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

メソッド定義が self で始まっているのが間違いです。 APIView サブクラスでメソッドを定義する場合は、self ではなく def を使用する必要があります。

このコードを試してください:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class BookViewer(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'get'})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'post'})

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

また、データ型を追加して urls.py コードを修正します。

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import BookViewer

urlpatterns = [
    path('book/<int:pk>/<str:option>/', BookViewer.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: 最初の文が変だったので修正しておきました。意図と違う場合は戻したり再修正してください。